# Macro Excel not responding after i run the program

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

hi i am new in vba so i have write a code to check if condition 1 is meet then it will go to the second condition and if meet it will go to the serial# sheet to post "a" in the D8 in and it run fine if i run 1 by 1 but when i run the macro it will show the not responding so anyone to help me?

condition 1 is sheet 1 row A1 = sheet 2 row A1 if yes then the second condition
if no then sheet2 row go to the next one A2 then it will ask the question again
condition 2 is sheet 1 row B1=sheet2 B1 if yes then go to serial# sheeet in D8 input a. 
if no then sheet2 row go to the next one b2 then it will ask the question again

but what i have done is that i split it to 4 sheet in total.
sheet1,sheet2.sheet3.shee4 
so is like:
sheet1 have the value of A1 of sheet1
sheet2 have the value of B1 of sheet1
sheet3 have the value of A1 of sheet2
sheet4 have the value of B1 of sheet2

this is how it look from sheet1 is the data that is key in and sheet 2 is the total it should have.
sheet1
row
A-B
1-1
1-2
1-3
1-4
2-1
2-2
2-3
2-4
3-1
3-2
3-3

sheet2
row
A-B
1-1
1-2
1-3
1-4
1-5
2-1
2-2
2-3
2-4
2-5
3-1
3-2
3-3
3-4
3-5
this is the code that i use:

```
Sub comapre()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim panel1, panel2, arr1, arr2

Sheets("working_files").Select
Range("A1").Select
panel1 = ActiveCell.Value
Sheets("working_files2").Select
Range("A1").Select
arr1 = ActiveCell.Value
Sheets("working_files3").Select
Range("A1").Select
panel2 = ActiveCell.Value
Sheets("working_files4").Select
Range("A1").Select
arr2 = ActiveCell.Value
Sheets("serial#").Select
Range("D8").Select

line1:
For i = i To 3
Sheets("working_files").Select
If IsNumeric(ActiveCell) Then
    If panel1 = panel2 Then
        If arr1 = arr2 Then
        Sheets("serial#").Select
        ActiveCell.Value = ("a")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        GoTo line2
        Else
        Sheets("working_files4").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        arr2 = ActiveCell.Value
        GoTo line1
        End If
    Else
    Sheets("serial#").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Sheets("working_files3").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    panel2 = ActiveCell.Value
    GoTo line1
    End If
Else
GoTo line3
End If
Next

line2:
Sheets("working_files").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
panel1 = ActiveCell.Value
Sheets("working_files2").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
arr1 = ActiveCell.Value
Sheets("working_files3").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
panel2 = ActiveCell.Value
Sheets("working_files4").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
arr2 = ActiveCell.Value
GoTo line1

line3:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using the message function to write to the screen what it is doing?

Comment: what is a message function?? i just start using vba one week agot.

Comment: It would be a lot more useful if you could provide samples of your sheet. I think by `message function` @SolarMike is refereeing to **`Msgbox`** function. In your VBA, just type `Msgbox "hello"` and it will popup a window saying **"Hello"**

Comment: thanks but i don know how to add a simple to here. do you mind telling me how to add a simple?

Comment: PRobably you are trapped in those loops you defined with `GoTo line`

Comment: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)